# Function to convert logic packed arrays of arbitrary value to string

Tags: casting, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to write a function that takes as input a `logic[:]` value of arbitrary length to a string. But, I am unable to find a correct way of implementing it.

I have tried the following approach:

```
function string bin_to_string (input logic _bin_ [] );
    automatic string _str_;

    _str_ = "";
    for(int i=0; i< _bin_.size(); i++) begin
        automatic string tmpstr; 
        tmpstr.bintoa(_bin_[i]);
        _str_ = {_str_, tmpstr };
    end
    return _str_;
endfunction : bin_to_string
```

Which raises the following error:

> Arg. '*bin*' of 'bin_to_string':  Cannot assign a packed type 'reg[3:0]' to an unpacked type 'reg $[]'.

Is creating a generic cast function for arbitrary length registers possible?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you show is from calling the function, not its implementation. You need to stream the packed array argument to an unpacked array.

```
mystring = bin_to_string( {>>{ input_arg }} );
```

Also, you have a typo in that `size` is never defined. But it would be easier to use `foreach( _bin_[i] )` instead